# Select specific columns by SHOW TABLE STAUS query

Tags: mysql, status

I have to select specific columns by the SHOW TABLE STATUS query. Now it looks like:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS IN  `myTableName` WHERE  `NAME` LIKE  '%name_substring%';
```

...and returns all columns. Is there any way to reach that goal?

Comment: May I ask, what information are you hoping to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query information_schema.TABLES in order to get specific columns. 
Check demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38506/3

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTableName';
```

Hope this helps